# (R) Graphs in a loop and funktion are empty, even though they work when plottet standalone

Tags: r, function, for-loop, ggplot2, x11

So, I have a boxplot where i annotate the number of datapoint per plot and significance levels in letters above the plots. When plottet in a normal (?!?) workflow, they take about 1-2 seconds to plot in a X Window System Graphics (X11), the plot gets saved afterwards. When the plot-command is wrapped in a for-loop or called by a function, the X11-window stays empty and gets saved like that.

Here is a minimal example using mtcars, showcasing the same problem. Without context this example does not make sense.

```
library(ggplot2)
setwd("C:/")
output <- "C:/"

data <- mtcars
data$cyl <- as.factor(data$cyl)

#----normal plotting----

x11()
ggplot(data, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar")+
  geom_boxplot()

savePlot(paste0(output, "example_normal", ".tiff"), type = "tiff")
dev.off()

#----plotting throught a function----

my.plot <- function(x)
{
  x11()
  ggplot(x, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+
    stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar")+
    geom_boxplot()
  
  savePlot(paste0(output, "example_function", ".tiff"), type = "tiff")
  dev.off()
}

my.plot(data)
```

Cheers

Comment: You are most probably a victim of lazy evaluation when using a `for` loop and non standard evaluation ([NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)) when using a function.  But without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: Also, `x-values` and `y-values` look suspicious.  Did you mean to type `x.values` or `x_values` by any chance?

Comment: The x-values and y-values are just placeholder because i didn´t want to post my specific vektors because they are not intuitive.
i´ll work on a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example with mtcars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to post a `print(ggplot(...))` around it to make it work in a for-loop.